# How to export email settings from an android device to another one?

Tags: sync, stock-email-app

I have configured the stock-email application of my phone to use my four imap accounts. This is quite long and I would rather avoid repeating this for my tablet. How can I export my email settings smoothly ?

I want to point out that I don't use gmail, nor K9 mail.

Thanks!